# ReactNative Navigation to a screen in the same direcotry

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am very new to react native and I had one question to ask. I have two screens in the same directory

screens:
Pro.js
Register.js

in Pro.js , there is one button to navigate to Register.js

```
  <Button
  textStyle={{ fontFamily: 'montserrat-regular', fontSize: 12 }}
  style={styles.button}
  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Register")}>
  GET STARTED
  </Button>
```

When I run above, I get below error:

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Register"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'Register'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production.
```

Can anyone help me to navigate to that page?

Comment: your screen is defined in the navigator with name Register

Comment: Are you defining your screens in a [navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation#creating-a-native-stack-navigator)? If so could you share that code?

Answer (score 0):

Check below code:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import RegisterScreen from './RegisterScreen';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is the Home screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Register"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Register')}
      />
    </View>
  );
};


export default HomeScreen
```

**RegisterScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

const RegisterScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is the Register screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default RegisterScreen
```